# iOS: What is a search list of UserDefault.standard?

Tags: ios

You can see an explanation of `UserDefault.standard` [here.](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/userdefaults/1416603-standard)

I am not clear of the explanation.  They say the instance has some different domains, but why does the instance have them?
In my understand, the instance `UserDefault.standard` corresponds to one user.  However, the instance has multiple domains such as global domains and application inherent domains. To sum up, does it have all information for the user?

I am little bit confused.  Could you explain?

Answer (score 0):

The domains are not applicable for iOS, they are supposed to be used with OSX:

> **Defaults Are Grouped into Domains in OS X**
>
> OS X preferences are grouped by domains so that system preferences can be differentiated from app preferences. Splitting preferences in this manner lets the user specify some preferences globally and then override one or more of those preferences inside an app. ([c](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i))

It allows to adjust preferences life-cycle and share them between apps. For more details please refer to [the manual](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/AboutPreferenceDomains/AboutPreferenceDomains.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i-CH2-SW1).

In iOS the `standard` preferences are always the same file (for an application). You can specify name for suite through the [`init(suiteName:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/userdefaults/1409957-init) to share preferences among an app group (please refer to [this guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html) for more details).

Comment: Thanks. Still not clear.  By the documentation, the `default` is consisted of `NSArgumentDomain`, A domain identified by the application’s bundle identifier, `NSGlobalDomain`, Separate domains for each of the user’s preferred languages and `NSRegistrationDomain`.  What do you mean by "`standard` preferences are always the same file"?

Comment: @KazuyaTomita, as I said, iOS doesn't have domain-specific preferences like MacOS has. It means that each time you ask for access through the UserDefaults.standard property in iOS, you deal with the same preferences within an app.